# Euclidean division on naturals in coq

Tags: coq

Is there a function for performing euclidean division on naturals in the Coq standard library?  I have been unable to find one.  If there isn't one, then is there a reason, mathematically, that there shouldn't be one?

The reason I want this is because I am trying to split a list into two smaller lists. I would like one list to be approximately half the size of the other, so I am computing (length xs) / 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4/stdlib/Coq.Numbers.Natural.Abstract.NDiv.html

Other euclidean things:

http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4/stdlib/Coq.Arith.Euclid.html

http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4/stdlib/Coq.Numbers.NatInt.NZDiv.html

http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4/stdlib/Coq.ZArith.Zdiv.html

http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/V8.4/stdlib/Coq.ZArith.Zeuclid.html

Comment: Is there a way to get the / division syntax from the first library without defining it myself?

Comment: I tried but did not succeed... The module system can be annoying when trying to get a notation in scope...